# Trying to run "C:\Program Files\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown.exe" -f -v in Powershell

Tags: powershell

In command line

```
"C:\Program Files\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown.exe" -f -v'
```

runs good; no error, but when I try to run same command in powershell using

```
"& cmd /c"
```

it is failing.

> PS C:\Users\user1>  $command = & cmd.exe /C '"C:\Program Files\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown"' -f -v
>   cmd.exe :
>   At line:1 char:13
>   +  $command = & cmd.exe /C '"C:\Program Files\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpd ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Any help here? I am not able to execute this cmd.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can run executables just like cmd without invoking `cmd.exe`:

```
$output = & "$Env:ProgramFiles\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown.exe" -f -v
```

Comment: I tried, but same error buddy.
PS C:\Users\user1> $output = & "$Env:ProgramFiles\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown.exe" -f -v
bpdown.exe : 
At line:1 char:11
+ $output = & "$Env:ProgramFiles\VERITAS\NetBackup\bin\bpdown.exe" -f - ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: @RonakPatel `> RemoteException` I feel like you're not telling the full story.

Comment: It looks like when i run it from PS ISE i am getting exception but when i run it from powershell command line its working good. not sure what is the difference.